# Meal times in Ireland

Tags: food-and-drink, local-customs, ireland

My fiancee and I will be visiting Ireland next October for our honeymoon. We will stay there for a couple of weeks, and we will stay both in cities, like Dublin and Galway, and smaller villages.

What are the usual meal times in Ireland? I don't want to be late for our dinner, and then starve all night long…

Comment: Ciao Lucia! ;) You mean in pubs/restaurants/hotels?

Comment: @JoErNanO yes, wherever it is possible to eat.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From personal experience, dinner in Ireland is between 6 and 9 PM but in some cases later.

I usually eat early and did get dinners at 6 PM, many diners did come in around 7, the time I left, but in some more expensive places people would just come in around that time and make reservations for later in the evening.

I would say, like in many countries, it depends on the class of restaurant as well as on the location.
So if you want to go for a late dinner, walk or call in earlier in the evening and try to make a reservation.

For lunch I tend to do sandwiches but on the few occasions that I had a day tour, the lunch stop was between noon and 2 PM, likely pubs and restaurants have lunch then, maybe lasting a bit longer.

Of course, there are all day food places, which close when the local shops do, but those are not restaurants nor pubs.

Answer (score 8):

For dinner (in the evening) from 6 to 9ish is when people would start.

Lunch is around 12 noon to 2pm, with 1pm being the most popular.

Some restaurants may have "early bird" offers, where you can eat cheaper if you start (and hence finish) earlier (i.e. start before/at 5:30pm).

A restaurant might be open until midnight, but may not be serving food all night. The kitchen might close at 9:30 or 10pm (i.e. they won't cook you any food, so you can't turn up at 10pm and get dinner). If in doubt, ask the restaurant "When do you stop serving food?" or "When does the kitchen close?". Some places are open much later.

Many restaurants or cafes would be open for a long period in the afternoon, so you can always get a meal then. It just might be lonely sitting in a restaurant on your own. Conversely lunch/dinner, there might be no free space for you, since everyone else is eating around then.

Answer (score -3):

typical dinnertime in Ireland is 1pm. Then we have some tea and toast around 6. Hope this is helpful for your upcoming trip!

Comment: The 'upcoming' trip was nearly five years ago. In any case, I simply don't believe that any worthwhile hostelry will serve only tea and toast at 6pm. I don't think you've understood the question.